# Configuring Salesforce LWC Local Dev Server on MacOS / Chrome - 500 Error When Calling Apex with Wire

Tags: salesforce, apex, lwc

I'm working on a LWC (lightning web component), and have been using the [Salesforce Local Development Server](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/localdev/lwclocaldev) successfully, until the point where I use a wire call to invoke the Apex function. I am getting a server 500 error, and it saying that the aura.token is not getting passed through as a parameter. I am able to create a record into the connected scratch org using Lightning Data Service, which is why I am confused, because it appears like it isn't having a problem connecting to the scratch org.

This is a pretty niche error, so any help would be appreciated. Full error msg seen below.

```
{"error":[{"message":"error parsing apex response: */{\"event\":{\"descriptor\":\"markup://aura:systemError\",\"attributes\":{\"values\":{\"message\":\"Missing parameter value for aura.token\",\"showOverride\":false}}},\"exceptionMessage\":\"Missing parameter value for aura.token\",\"exceptionEvent\":true}/*ERROR*/"}
```

PS: I know it's not an issue with the actual function or JS b/c it works when I deploy it in the UI of the scratch org. I am 90% sure it is an issue with how the Local Dev Server is configured, but can't quite put my finger on it after 2-3 days of banging my head against the wall.